# Writing a script in Java that regularly requests data from a website

Tags: java, load, xmlhttprequest

I'm working on a project that requires me to use information on border wait times provided by the Canadian Border Patrol on their [website](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/bwt-taf/menu-eng.html) to construct a visual representation of wait time distribution.

I'm trying to find a way to have a Java script regularly check the website, and extract the information at a few different border stations (not all of them). I suppose I would use XPath to get me the specific stations, but how do I load up the webpage on a regular basis?

(P.S. I know they have a Twitter account too now, but they update it once a day and more specifically I'd like to learn how to work with websites and XPATH)

Comment: basically you have to implement AJAX with a timer code. It will very easy to implement using jQuery library. AJAX will work for you if have API access of the Website concerned. Or else you have to build some backend solution to scrape the data from that website

Comment: You mean Javascript, not Java, right? If so please fix the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok i had a little time off today at job and thought to give a help and write it for you. Excuse me for any mistakes it's the first time i parsed a site, i made a little research and decided to use jSoup for this.

Ok this code will parse the table and system out the 3 columns with the values, you can alter the code and build it within your needs :)

You have to download the jsoup jar [Download jSoup](http://jsoup.org/download)

`import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;


/**
 * 
 */
public class ParseWithJsoup{


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        URL url;

        try {

            url = new URL("http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/bwt-taf/menu-eng.html");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("");

            String inputLine = "";

            // Append the site in a buffer
            while (inputLine != null){
                inputLine = buffRead.readLine();
                buffer.append(inputLine);
            }

            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(buffer.toString());

            // Parse the table
            Element table = doc.select("table[class=bwt]").first();

            //Office elements iterator
            Iterator<Element> officeElements = table.select("td[headers=Office]").iterator();

            //Commercial Flow iterator
            Iterator<Element> comElements = table.select("td[headers=Com ComCanada]").iterator();

            //Travellers Flow iterator
            Iterator<Element> travElements = table.select("td[headers=Trav TravCanada]").iterator();


            // Iterate all elements through first element row for all columns
            while(officeElements.hasNext()){            
                System.out.println("Office: " + officeElements.next().text());
                System.out.println("Commercial Flow: " + comElements.next().text());
                System.out.println("Travellers Flow: " + travElements.next().text());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exc:"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }


}`

`

Answer (score 4):

Use the URL in Java. Create the URL and then use its method .openConnection() to start reading from the website.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;


public class webVisitor {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        URL url;

        try {

            url = new URL("http://seinfeldaudio.com");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine = "";

            while (inputLine != null){
                inputLine = buffRead.readLine();
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }


        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }

    }

}
```

More info here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-url-content-in-java/

Comment: So you answered your own question and selected that as an answer ?

Comment: Anyway, you will also require some sort of push mechanism to update the UI with the new data. You may want to look at Comet push notifications for the same.

Comment: @happybuddha Ya basically. It was taking a long time to get an answer, so I took out a book and figured most of it out. Stackoverflow welcomes OP's answering their own questions btw

Comment: 28 February i gave the exact answer for your question OP, i have even tested it and parsed the data, your answer is a generic answer in how to read the html data and print them, you have asked for XPATH parsing, but ok your question your answer :)

Comment: @ThomasSofras I really do appreciate your answer, but I accepted mine since I had already done the research and posted my answer before yours was up. Nonetheless, out of appreciation, and because your answer is in fact better I will switch my accept :)

Comment: Really appreciate your stance :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Ajax using `setInterval("function()",x)`

Refer to this question - [Repeat jQuery ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140939/repeat-jquery-ajax-call)

I've not got around to learning [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) but this loos like something that would be well suited to it

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DWR (Easy Ajax for Java)](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) ,call the DWR method from your java script by setting the time interval as

```
setInterval(DWR function here , millisec, lang)
```

In Java method use java.net.URL Class to read and parse the content as  required.