# Am I using "data" correctly in my function

Tags: jquery, json, razor

I'm new to jQuery and I was wondering if I am passing my JSON data correctly into the function.

If I am saying something incorrectly or there is more information I need to provide. Please feel free to let me know! Thank you for all the help! Much appreciated!

According to Chrome Developer Tools. I get this error:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'GhStatus' of undefined
```

Here is my function:

```
        function MachineOffChecker() {
                var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("index","GhCs"))';
                $.get(url, window.setInterval(
                                function(data) {                                                        
                                    if (data.GhStatus == 0) {                                                  
                                        $('#GhCsStatus_CS').buttonMarkup({ icon: 'myapp-cs' });     
                                       alert('crash');
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        $('#GhCsStatus_GH').buttonMarkup({ icon: 'myapp-gh' });      
                                        alert('running');
                                    }
                                    if (data.CsStatus == 0) {                                                 
                                        $('#GhCsStatus_CS').buttonMarkup({ icon: 'myapp-cs' });     
                                        alert('crash');
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        $('#GhCsStatus_GH').buttonMarkup({ icon: 'myapp-gh' });     
                                        alert('running');
                                    }
                                }, 2000), "json");                                                  
            }
```

This is my JSON data:

```
    {
        "GhStatus": 0,
        "CsStatus": 0
    }
```

Comment: window.setInterval where you used it doesn't make sense. $.get expects a function, an object, an array, or a string as it's 2nd argument. you gave it an integer.

Comment: @tymeJV - no it does not! It would call the ajax method, but not as intended.

Comment: @adeneo -- Just making sure...never seen the `window.setInterval` used where it is.

Comment: The setInterval is a function, so it would work, but it would keep calling that function over and over, which makes no sense,

Comment: @adeneo the specific function im doing uses setInterval so I need it haha

Comment: @KevinB my second argument is a function. My first argument in .get() is a string (url)

Comment: Your second argument is the integer that is returned by `window.setInterval()`. Try it yourself. `alert(window.setInterval(function(){},1000));` it's an integer, not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
 window.setInterval(
     $.get(url,function(data) {                                                        
        if (data.GhStatus == 0) {                                                  
           $('#GhCsStatus_CS').buttonMarkup({ icon: 'myapp-cs' });     
           alert('crash');
        }else{
           $('#GhCsStatus_GH').buttonMarkup({ icon: 'myapp-gh' });      
           alert('running');
        }

        if (data.CsStatus == 0) {                                                 
           $('#GhCsStatus_CS').buttonMarkup({ icon: 'myapp-cs' });     
           alert('crash');
        }else{
           $('#GhCsStatus_GH').buttonMarkup({ icon: 'myapp-gh' });     
           alert('running');
        }
     }, "json")
 ,2000);
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! I'm switching over to this format!

Comment: I have a question. If both my values are 0, crash pop up should appear every 2 seconds correct?

Comment: if both values are 0. then every two seconds crash will pop up twice.

Comment: hmmm crash pops up twice but only one iteration occurs. I thought it would occur every 2 seconds =/ i'll have to look and try again

Comment: wrap the `$.get` stuff in a function then give that function to `setInterval`. Call setInterval with `$(document).ready` See example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5140963/2456100

Comment: This is my code. http://pastebin.com/X2PXDT9Z The function runs only once and then i get errors =[

Comment: Well the function() runs once well but after that I get errors at the set intervaL

Answer (score 1):

You should set your dataType to json. Or you can use $.getJSON().

Edit:

You need the quotes "json"

Comment: he did at least try to do that, `JSON` should have been `"JSON"`

Comment: Should be "json", no?

Comment: either or should work, it gets put to lowercase by jQuery. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/ajax.js#L69