# Pause and resume ajax repeated request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In order to code posted by Wiktor (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43338063/7666076) how to pause and resume sending ajax requestes after click on some button (two different buttons like 'pause' and 'play').

Also how to break the current ajax request immediatelly after click on "pause" button. I don't want to wait for new data which will be fetched by ajax query.

Here is my adapted code:

```
function RefreshData()
{
    console.log('Sending AJAX request...');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getAjaxRequest.php?"+device+"&callback=?",
        dataType: "jsonp"
    }).done(function(dataJSON) {
        adaptJsonData(dataJSON);
        console.log('success');
    }).fail(function() {
        console.log('error');
    }).always(function() {
        intervalTime = 100;
        console.log('Waiting '+intervalTime+' miliseconds...');
        setTimeout(RefreshData, intervalTime);
    });

    return true;
}

function adaptJsonData(dataJSON) {
    # ... some logic with dataJSON object
}
```

Comment: Assing `$.ajax(...` to a variable, then you can abort the ongoing request like `foo.abort()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var xhr = null;
function RefreshData() {
    if( xhr != null ) {
       xhr.abort();
        xhr = null;
    }
    xhr = $.ajax({'...'});
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

The Beneris answer is quite good for aborting current $.ajax request, but this not resolve the `setTimeout(function, time)` usage in .always function.

### So I've solved my problem by:

1. Define global variables: 
   `var xhr = null` - which handling ajax xhr object, and 
   `var timer` - which handling `setTimeout` reference.
2. As Beneris advice, assign the `$.ajax({...})` to the `xhr` variable:

```js
var xhr = null; // global variable
var timer; // global variable
function RefreshData() {
    xhr = $.ajax({...});
}
```

3. In `.always()` method assing `timer` reference to `setTimeout()`

```js
xhr = $.ajax({})
    .done(function(){})
    .fail(function(){})
    .always(function(){
        timer = setTimeout(RefreshData, 100);//refresh every 100 msec
    });
```

4. Now I can manipulate the ajax requests using jQuery by:

```js
$('button.pause').click(function() {
    xhr.abort(); // xhr is in global scope; remove/comment this line if You don't need to abort last ajax request
    xhr = null; // remove/comment this line too if You don't need to abort last ajax request
    clearTimeout(timer); // timer variable is the reference to setTimeout
});
$('button.resume').click(function() {
    RefreshData();
});
```

If somebody need this functionality 
without aborting last ajax request, just delete the line `xhr.abort()`.

### How it works?

## Aborting the current ajax request:

> The $.ajax() function returns the XMLHttpRequest object that it
>   creates. Normally jQuery handles the creation of this object
>   internally, but a custom function for manufacturing one can be
>   specified using the xhr option. The returned object can generally be
>   discarded, but does provide a lower-level interface for observing and
>   manipulating the request. In particular, calling .abort() on the
>   object will halt the request before it completes.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

## Destroy the `setTimeout` method for stop refreshing:

To clear some `setTimeout` stuff, just use `clearTimeout(<the_setTimeout_reference>)`

https://www.wittysparks.com/forums/topic/how-to-kill-or-cancel-or-remove-settimeout-with-cleartimeout/